# Why is default construction disallowed in std::span with static extent?

Tags: c++, c++20

Take a look at this example:

```cpp
#include <span>
#include <vector>

class Data
{
public:
    Data() = default;
  
    template<class R>
    explicit Data(R& r)
        : buf_(r) 
        , header_(buf_.first<4>())
    {}

private:
    std::span<char> buf_;

    // compile error
    // std::span<char, 4> header_;

    // compiles but ill-formed (against the precondition of [span.sub])
    std::span<char, 4> header_{buf_.first<4>()};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> buf(1234);
    Data data{buf};
}
```

The reason of compile error is because it is explicitly disallowed in the standard [[span.cons]](http://eel.is/c++draft/views#span.cons-1):

> ```cpp
> constexpr span() noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Constraints:* `Extent == dynamic_­extent || Extent == 0` is true.
> *Postconditions:* `size() == 0 && data() == nullptr`.

**Why does this constraint exist?**

Since default construction for a span with `dynamic_extent` is already allowed, it feels like these two cases are semantically same:

```
std::span<char> header_; // allowed
std::span<char, 4> header_; // why disallowed?
```

Furthermore, take a look at the wording of [[span.obs]](http://eel.is/c++draft/views#span.obs):

> ```cpp
> constexpr size_type size() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Effects:* Equivalent to: `return size_­;`

Let's say for example, the standard could even define stricter implementation details to encourage static optimization. If this wording was something like `Returns Extent when Extent != dynamic_extent`, the `size_` data member can be omitted in runtime. If so, I understand that the default construction is invalid, because in that case `size()` will always return invalid size, i.e. `Extent`, which is not zero.

However, current standard exposes the non-static member variables in the class definition [[span.overview]](http://eel.is/c++draft/views#span.overview-2):

```cpp
  private:
    pointer data_;              // exposition only
    size_type size_;            // exposition only
```

Since we already have those variables, can't the standard library just set `data_ = nullptr` and `size_ = 0` when statically sized span is default constructed? I surely can live with the current wording, but isn't the current standard expecting too strong constraints?

Note that the committee have once attempted to fix [span.cons] already in [LWG3198](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3198), so I'm pretty sure that they have some rationale for current wording.

Comment: "*Since we already have those variables*" You don't have those variables. They are "exposition only", meaning that they don't have to exist. They're there to make it easier to talk about what the various functions do. Implementations behave *as if* these variables exist, but if the implementation can work without creating such members, then it may do so.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I have misunderstood the meaning of "exposition only" in the spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A default-constructed `std::span<T>` successfully refers to 0 objects of type `T` starting at `nullptr`.  To what 3 objects of type `T` does `std::span<T,3>()` refer?

The `size_` member always being present is purely a narrative device to simplify the specification; it means nothing and really isn’t there in practice for static-extent spans.

Comment: `std::span<T, 3>` *could* be read as "statically expects 3 elements of T, but the actual object storage is up to runtime initialization." I feel like this is permissible because pure runtime initialization of static span is allowed (such as `std::span{vec}.first<3>()`). In this case the `first<3>()` part won't be able to recognize whether the parent object actually holds 3 objects until runtime. How do you feel about this point of view?

Comment: @saki7: `std::span<int>().first<3>()` has undefined behavior, but the type system can’t tell that (by definition).  Why supply a constructor that would, to avoid invalidating downstream invariants, *always* have undefined behavior?  I guess your real question is “Is there such an invariant?”, to which the answer is yes.

Comment: @saki7: The whole point of a static extent span is that it is static -- the number of elements is fixed at compile time.  Making it semi-dynamic would essentially impose all the additional overhead of a dynamic extent, so why not just use a dynamic extent?  Your example extracting a static extent from a dynamic extent will throw an exception (and never try to create the static extent span even temporarily) if the source is not large enough.

Comment: @saki7: "*std::span<T, 3> could be read as "statically expects 3 elements of T*" What it "could be read as" is irrelevant; what it *is* is an array of 3 elements.

Comment: Sounds fair enough, I am convinced by the explanation. Could you take a look at my workaround which I just posted as an another answer? Is there any smart ways to accomplish the optimization like I'm expecting?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does this constraint exist?

Because that's what it means to ask for or specify the size of a `span`. If you are given a `span`, *any `span`*, the expectation is that `span::size` will return the number of elements in the array. Period.

If you create a `span` with X elements in it, you are required to provide a pointer range that actually stores X elements in it. You may of course lie to `span`, passing it a pointer to fewer elements. But you are breaking your part of the contract; you said that there were X elements in the array, and you provided fewer than X. The UB that results is on you.

It doesn't matter if X is a runtime or compile-time value: the requirement is the same.

To default-construct a statically-sized `span` is to allow the user to lie *by default*. A default-initialized `span<T, 3>` is lying to every user that gets one. It claims to have 3 elements, but it does not.

Good APIs do not let users lie to it by default.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to write this kind of code when no other solution is available:

```cpp
inline static std::array<char, 4> dummy_header_v;
std::span<char, 4> header_{dummy_header_v};
```

Personally, this is just a nasty workaround and I really don't like it.

However, there is some benefit for this workaround: *the user can expect compiler optimization* (such as loop unrolling) whenever one reads from `Data::header_`, since it is statically sized span `std::span<T, N>` in the first place. This is useful when you already know the partial buffer size by definition, and when you're going to fetch the real buffer lazily. If the span was declared like `std::span<T>`, no optimization will ever happen.

If the spec allow default construction, then there's no need of this workaround.

I posted this workaround just for reference; I really appreciate other proper solutions.

Comment: If you want a maybe-span, that’s what `std::optional` is for.  (Ideally, the library would recognize the opportunity of using `nullptr` as the disengaged state, but we’re not usually that lucky.)

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes, `std::optional` is certainly one of the available candidates. But you know, `std::optional` has some overhead (for null-state), and I assume that the nullable storage of `std::optional<std::span<T>>` can be essentially equal to the data pointer member of `std::span<T>` itself. If we could place `nullptr` there, problem solved. I think that the C++ standard is not defined like what I'm thinking, and I'm looking for functionality which just does not exist - if I interpret your comment correctly.

Comment: The standard allows `std::optional<std::span<T,3>>` to be implemented in a clever way involving unions, but I think most implementations consider it to be not worth the special effort.